# NextJS upgrade to version 13 is resulting in 404 page not found error

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I use a custom Express server along with NextJS. I upgraded NextJS from 12.x to 13.4.19 as per the migration guide provided in their docs. After the upgrade, my app's main page is returning a 404 - not found error because it is not able to find the route that I had defined in my existing code.

I'm using the pages folder structure at root level as per the older version.

[image: pages folder for routing]

In my server.js file, I have this existing code that used to work fine earlier as it used to load the pages/index.js file. However, it's no more able to locate that file somehow.

```
app.get("/dashboard"], (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, "/");
  });
```

Interesting part here is, it can still render the contents of the 404.js file from the same folder when it can't render the route mentioned above.

I have tried creating another folder inside pages folder and adding an index.js file inside that one, while also using this route in the server.js file, but didn't work.

I also have an existing src folder and all my components, utils, etc. are under src/app. I did suspect that maybe as per [this doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/src-directory) the router is getting confused between src/app directory and the pages directory at the root level. So I tried renaming the src/app to something else, but it still didn't work.

Please help!

Comment: I have found a similar (or maybe exactly same) issue reported here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48260